# How do I disable the auto-mounting of internal drives in Ubuntu or Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, kubuntu, automount

I am running Kubuntu 18.04 w/ KDE Plasma 5.12.6 off of a USB drive. This is a full install, not a Live version. The drive serves as a portable system that I can use with most physical computers.

To prevent any damage to the host computer's data. I do not want to automount any internal disk drives on boot. Even better, I'd like to completely disable those drives, so that even a normal `sudo mount /dev/sdx` wouldn't work, but I'll settle for disabaling auto-mounting to start.

#### What I've tried

- The most commonly cited answer is to change the `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount` setting to false. I've done this using both `gsettings` from the command line as well as the `dconf` gui editor. Both automount and automount-open are set to false
- Removing my account (and all accounts) from the plugdev group.
- Confirming that the "Enable automatic mounting of removable media" setting in the Kubuntu `Removeable Devices` settings module is unchcked.

After trying all of these and rebooting, Kubuntu still mounts all discovered partitions, both those on the flash drive and any found on internal drives.

#### Solutions that won't work

- The other oft-mentioned solution is to disable the auto-mounting of specific devices by adding the device  `fstab` along with a `noauto` option. This solution does not help in my scenario, as I do not know what devices will be present when the system starts up. I would need to somehow configure fstab to default with a noauto for all devices.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170549/how-to-disable-automount-for-external-devices-in-opensuse-13-2

Comment: @Panther thanks, that worked. As the question/solution is for an older version of Linux, and specifically marked for openSUSE, do you want to write up your comment as an answer? Based on other questions, I think that this is a fairly common request, especially for Kubuntu.

Comment: @BrianHVP go ahead , give credit as to the source

Comment: I found the solution: [write a custom udev rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369166).

Comment: Did not work on Debian 10 buster.

Comment: For me, the best solution (for systemd based systems) is to create a "hidden-partition.rule" according to this post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/236315/hide-boot-drive-from-nautilus/236323#236323 It really works perfectly, also on current Kubuntu releases like 20.04 LTS. :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Auto-mounting of disks in Debian-based Linux distros (and perhaps others) comes from a service called [*udisks2*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks).

Disabling this service will prevent any disk from automatically being mounted, while still allowing manual mounting.

Disable the service - No automatic or manual starts

```
systemctl mask udisks2
```

Unmask the service - Will need to either manually run it or restart the computer

```
systemctl unmask udisks2
systemctl unmask udisks2.service
```

Stop the service temporarily - This will not persist across restarts

```
systemctl stop udisks2.service
```

Get the status

```
systemctl status udisks2
```

Credit to @maxschlepzig for answering a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170549/how-to-disable-automount-for-external-devices-in-opensuse-13-2) about OpenSUSE.

Comment: Others have suggested that I edit the commands to prefix them all with `sudo`. While `sudo` may very well be required for many setups, I'm against explicitly including `sudo` in command examples, due to the risk they might be copied and pasted by less experienced users. The message you get when running a command that requires elevation is clear enough that I don't think even Linux novices would have trouble understanding that the need to repeat the command with `sudo` prefixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the original question, but a comment that I had an unwanted side-effect with this solution on Ubuntu 18.04 using cinnamon. Disabling udisks2 helped for me too, but as described here [cannot start nemo if udisks2 is disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157832/cannot-start-nemo-if-udisks2-is-disabled) I then had the problem that file manager **nemo** did not start anymore. The solution for me was to disable the option "Automatic mount removable media when inserted and on startup" in the "Behavior" tab of nemo's preferences.