# cannot start nemo if udisks2 is disabled

Tags: nemo, udisks

I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with cinnamon as desktop and my default file browser is nemo.

I don't like that any partition of an external disk that I connect to my machine (e.g. via USB) is automatically mounted. I have found a solution to disable this behavior by stopping udisks2 (cf. [How do I disable the auto-mounting of internal drives in Ubuntu or Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062719/how-do-i-disable-the-auto-mounting-of-internal-drives-in-ubuntu-or-kubuntu-18-04)). After rebooting my machine I had to realize that nemo is not starting anymore. If I start it on the command line, I get the following output:

```
[ch730-19:~]$ nemo
(nemo:21961): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:23:11.051: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
(nemo:21961): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: 15:23:11.324: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported
```

After enabling udisks2 again and rebooting the machine, nemo works again, so I am sure that the missing udisks2 service is the reason for the problem. Does anyone have an idea how to get nemo running while udisks2 is disabled? Or is there another option to disable the automatic mounting of external disks?

Comment: Start Nemo go "Edit” –> “Preference” there mußt be a point to deactivate the behavior.

Comment: Really strange, this was already the solution. I was not aware of the fact that nemo is responsible for mounting external devices even if the application is not running; but it seems that there is alway a process `nemo-desktop` running in the background. After disabling option "Automatic mount removable media when inserted and on startup" (in the "Behavior" tab), the partitions are not mounted anymore. At least for my problem that was the solution, thank you!

Comment: Thanks fore converting, but I don't see th point. It was no link or something else. as short answer only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, the solution for my problem was to disable the automatic mounting my nemo itself. Therefore open nemo, go to "Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior" and disable the option "Automatically mount revmovable media when inserted and on startup". Then external disks are not mounted anymore automatically; and there is no need to disable the udisks2 service to prevent this automatic mounting.