# Unwanted Auto-mounting

Tags: boot, mount, automount, drive, 21.10

I have Ubuntu set to auto mount two of my drives, which it successfully does every time I boot the system.

However, sometimes shortly after I boot my system Ubuntu will start to mount the other five drives I have in my computer. It seems to mount these other drives in a different order every time, mounting one after another until all of the drives are mounted. It's quite annoying.

This issue has only started to affect me since upgrading to 21.10

The two drives that should auto mount are ext4 drives, the other drives are a combination of ext4 and NTFS drives. They are all internal SATA drives, some are SSD some are HDD.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: If you want to block *just* those drives/partitions from mounting, you could use the `noauto` flag in your `fstab` file. If you want to prevent *any* undefined drive/partition from auto-mounting, you could look at [disabling the `udisks2` service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062719/how-do-i-disable-the-auto-mounting-of-internal-drives-in-ubuntu-or-kubuntu-18-04) 