Temporarily inhibit automount
Occasionally, I plug an external storage medium into my system because I want to use low-level disk tools such as dd or some partitioning tool. Automount is undesirable in that case.
To this end, I usually start GParted before I plug in the drive, as GParted somehow inhibits mounts (I can’t even mount the drive manually while GParted is running).
But I’m wondering if there's a cleaner way to tell Ubuntu "this one time, do not automount the drive I'm about to insert" – without making that behavior permanent.

Hmm... what problem is there with a simple "unmount"?
$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7,3T  0 disk 
└─/dev/sda1        8:1    0  7,3T  0 part /media/hannu/Data8
...

$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sda1
Unmounted /dev/sda1.

$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7,3T  0 disk 
└─/dev/sda1        8:1    0  7,3T  0 part 
...

Note udisksctl mount does the same thing as an "automount"
Otherwise:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333721/78842 -  systemctl stop udisks2.service
https://askubuntu.com/a/1113439/289138 - more on systemctl mask udisks2
https://superuser.com/a/1038152/346288 - fstab

will something like UUID=[UUID] /[mount_point] ext4 defaults,noauto 0 0 in ~/etc/fstab also work? Rem it out when not required.

I have not got to the point to actually play with fstab in that manner, so; I do not know.

You can read about noauto in this superuser post

Well, included above ;-)

The problem with a simple unmount, apart from being inconvenient, is that the filesystem briefly gets mounted and the OS has the chance to mess with it (mount count, access time...).
